# OCaml Graphics issue on Windows

Tags: graphics, ocaml

Whenever I try and open a window using Ocaml Graphics, I receive the error:

```
Graphics.Graphic_failure "Cannot open display "
```

This is after already installing XMing and PuTTy. I am running Windows 10 and just running the following code in utop, for reference

```
#require "graphics";;
Graphics.open_graph "";;
```

Our teammate using a Mac can run graphics but nobody on Windows can.

Comment: What is your windows install? Cygwyn?

Comment: Also you may be interested in trying `Bogue` which includes a SDL library to draw as in graphics : https://sanette.github.io/bogue/Bogue.Sdl_area.html